# google pay and apple pay in flutter using pay package in flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, dependencies, applepay, google-pay

i am using google pay as my international payment method in my app using **pay: ^1.1.0 package** i am seeing the pay with google option in my emulator but not in real device in debug mode also what may be the reason and how can i test it whre do i find the card for google payment is picture is of real devide and second is of emulator  [this is my real device image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mhwC.jpg) [This is my emulator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntTvq.png)

i was expecting to show the button in real device also but it is not shown in the real device i tried to change the location of my country using VPN because i am living in nepal and google pay do not work work in nepal  but also it does't work

```
  String os = Platform.operatingSystem;

   const Center(
                      child: Text(
                    "or Pay with ",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: CgFontSize.headerThree,
                      color: CgColor.ghostWhite,
                    ),
                  )),
                  Center(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Platform.isIOS
                            ? ApplePayButton(
                                paymentConfiguration:
                                    PaymentConfiguration.fromJsonString(
                                        defaultApplePay),
                                paymentItems: _paymentItems,
                                style: ApplePayButtonStyle.black,
                                type: ApplePayButtonType.buy,
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                                onPaymentResult: ((result) {
                                  debugPrint("Payment Result $result");
                                  log(result.toString());
                                  BaseRequest().applePay(
                                    packageId: "",
                                    amount: "",
                                    paymentMethod: "",
                                    token: "",
                                  );
                                }),
                                loadingIndicator: const Center(
                                  child: LoadingProgressIndicator(),
                                ),
                              )
                            : GooglePayButton(
                                paymentConfiguration:
                                    PaymentConfiguration.fromJsonString(
                                        defaultGooglePay),
                                paymentItems: _paymentItems,
                                type: GooglePayButtonType.pay,
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                                onPaymentResult: ((result) {
                                  debugPrint("Payment Result $result");
                                  log(result.toString());
                                  BaseRequest().goglePay(
                                      packageId: "",
                                      amount: "",
                                      paymentMethod: "",
                                      token: "",
                                      productId: "");
                                }),
                                loadingIndicator: const Center(
                                  child: LoadingProgressIndicator(),
                                ),
                              ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: Found a solution yet?